# Node.js and Async error

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have node.js app structured like this:

```
async.forever(
function(callback) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            SomeFunction1(function(err, results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                callback(null, results);
            });
        },
        function(callback) {
            SomeFunction2(function(err, results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                callback(null, results);
            });
        },
        function(callback) {
            SomeFunction3(function(err, results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                callback(null, results);
            });
        },      
        ],
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            setTimeout(callback, 30000);
        });
},
function(err) {}
);
```

There should be 30s pause in async.forever cycle and functions SomeFunction1, SomeFunction2 and SomeFunction3 should be executed in series only once per cycle.

It works fine for a while, but after some time (sometimes couple of days) functions in async.series (SomeFunction1, SomeFunction2 and SomeFunction3) starts to run multiple time per async.forever cycle.
Logs show that every function runs 3 times couple of milliseconds apart.

I get no errors from node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why you don't do `async.series([SomeFunction1, SomeFunction2, SomeFunction3], …)`???

Comment: How do you know that it's the same `forever` cycle? Maybe it's just `setTimeout` that doesn't wait long enough?

Comment: @Bergi there is forever and series because series callback deals with errors from SomeFunctions and stops execution of that forever cycle but it should not stop forever completely, it just delay 30s and starts over.

Comment: @Bergi Any idea why 'setTimeout' would not wait long enough? Like I wrote, one time functions were executed 3 times, paralel, every forever cycle.

Comment: I understand what it is supposed to do, I just don't get why you have these overly complicated extra function expressions around each `SomeFunctionX`.

Comment: No, `setTimeout` not waiting long enough is pretty unlikely. The only thing I can think of (and that `async.js` does indeed not prevent) is when one of your `SomeFunction`s does invoke its callback multiple times. Do you think that can happen?

Comment: @Bergi Unlikely. In that case, only cycles where multiple callbacks were invoked would be executed multiple times. But in my case, after functions starts to be executed multiple times, they continue to be executed multiple times until I restart app, always same number of times.

Comment: No, that's exactly the pattern. A function executes its callback multiple times, which leads to the `series` callback being called multiple times, which leads to multiple `forever` cycles being started in parallel. Async.js seems to be pretty dumb in that regard.

Comment: @Bergi Hm, I must check to be sure, there is actualy 10 functions and it is obviusly some edge case since it happens so rarely. But at least now I know where to start, I was stuck with this for a long time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should I make this guess an answer?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I will mark it as an answer after I test and verify my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the functions starts to run multiple time per `async.forever` cycle

The only thing I can think of is that you have functions that call their callback multiple times. `async.js` does not care about this, and would happily fire off multiple cylces to run in parallel.

A good idea to counter such problems would be to use Promises instead. They are contracted by [the spec](http://promisesaplus.com/) to fire callbacks only once, and prevent to resolve them multiple times.